# How to extract the 'd' attribute programmatically from several svgs in a directory?

Tags: svg

I have hundreds of svgs in a directory. I would like to query the directory and extract the 'd' attribute of each svg.

All the svgs look like the one below:

```
<svg width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M16 32C7.163 32 0 24.837 0 16S7.163 0 16 0s16 7.163 16 16-7.163 16-16 16zm-.065-28C9.342 4.001 4 9.347 4 15.94c.001 6.592 5.347 11.936 11.94 11.935 6.592-.002 11.936-5.347 11.935-11.94A11.937 11.937 0 0015.935 4zm-4.847 5.23a.123.123"/></svg>
```

I appreciate the help.

I would love to make this solution on javascript but any other option would work too. Python, bash, etc.

Comment: Is this a one time operation you need to run? What's the OS or stack? Is it for web?

Comment: One time operation. I have it on my Mac but I also have a linux machine. Pretty much I want to extract some data and shove it in a Json file. I will use the Json to programmatically create icons based from those svgs. I have everything figured it out but I'm having trouble getting that 'd' attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting the answer that I found in the dark corners of NPM ;-).

The following package does exactly what I needed, which was to extract the full string of the attribute 'd' in the svg path.

Here it is:
[npm: extract-svg-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-svg-path)